# Get VLOOKUP to pick most recent date from a selection

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to get an Excel VLOOKUP to pick out the most recent date where it finds multiple lookup values:

e.g. this is what I have at the moment:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A$1:A$5635,'RSA Report'!A:V,21,FALSE),"")
```

it would currently pick (User1 acting as the value that is being looked up)

```
Col A (1)                       Col U (21)
User1                           22/10/2013
```

from

```
Col A (1)                       Col U (21)
User1                           22/10/2013
User1                           28/03/2014
User1                           22/10/2013
User1                           28/03/2014
```

whereas I want it to pick

```
Col A (1)                       Col U (21)
User1                           28/03/2014
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VLookup is designed to look for a single match for a specific value (either using an exact or approximate comparison). It doesn't check for any other matching values. I can think of 2 options which might help:

- If you can sort the data, sort Column U in descending order. The most recent date will then be returned as the first match.
- If you can't sort the data, you could consider using the [DMax](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/dmax-HP005209061.aspx) function. This allows you to specify criteria and then return the maximum value for a specific field. It does require you to put the criteria in a table format rather than specifying directly within the formula, so it's not ideal in all situations. Here's an example showing DMAX:

Formula: `=DMAX(B3:C7,"Date",E3:E4)`

This assumes that your table of data is in range B3:B7, you want to find the maximum value in a field called "Date" and your criteria is in range E3:E4 (where E3 contains the field name you are filtering on, and E4 contains the value you are looking for). One of the benefits of DMax is that you can use multiple sets of criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You should work sort your data before the vlookup.
Sort by the column A and add one more level sorting by column U (ordering by the most recent date)
Then you can do the Vlookup and it will return the first match, that will be the most recent date!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer] and follow the guideline for providing quality answer in case you haven't read that.

Comment: It's not clear what you're saying, but I think you might just be repeating the other answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
=Max(if(sheet2$A:$A=sheet1A1,Sheet2$B:$B))
```

Where `sheet2` is data sheet and `sheet1` is where you want to do lookup.
End formula with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>.